# sendmail with cron job

Tags: cron, sendmail

I've written a script and everything is working so well according to my needs:

```
a=$(df -h /mnt/smb | tail -n +3 | tr -s ' ' | tr '%' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5)
echo $a

if [[ $a -ge 30 ]]; then
    cat /etc/diskspace/text.txt | sendmail test.gmail.com
fi
```

I want to run this script every minute via Cron, see my crontab:

```
* * * * * /etc/diskspacae/vpndrive.sh
```

As you can see, after running this script if drive space is more than 80%, I want to use sendmail to get a notification in my email.

But I haven't got it when I've run this script from Cron, and I've got this error message in `/var/spool/mail/root`.

```
ERROR Message: /etc/diskspace/vpndrive.sh line 34 : sendmail: command not found.
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't forget that script executed by Cron are ran in an environment with a limited PATH variable.
This means that on the console when you test your script, the console shell will find **sendmail** without problem. But when ran from Cron, **sendmail** is not found.

Best practise when writing scripts for Cron is to put the full path to access the command you want to run, just to be sure.

Usually, the **sendmail** binary is install under `/usr/sbin`, a path which is not part of the directories looked up by Cron by default. So I would advise to :

1. Look for the place of **sendmail** binary (`locate sendmail` or `find / -type f -name sendmail)` if `locate` is not installed)
2. Write down the full path to execute **sendmail** in your script

Comment: just type `which sendmail` to find the location

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `sendmail` is not installed.

To install it type `sudo apt-get install sendmail` in terminal.

For further configuration visit similar question: [how to configure sendmail on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu)

Comment: **sendmail** was so widely used at some time that all the MTA packages I know (**sendmail** obviously! - **postfix** - **ssmtp**) install a binary or symlink called `sendmail` to submit mails from command line and script.